# How do I configure my Asus WL-520GU to support my F2238's flatbed scanner for MacOS X?

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-leopard, scanner

I have an Asus WL-520GU and an HP Deskjet F2238. I want to be able to wirelessly scan documents to client computers. I think this is possible but I'm not sure how to set this up. Any pointers?